# Distributing android apps on sd cards

Tags: android

Is it possible to distribute android apps on sd cards? In this case, it is to distribute an app with an embedded video to customers along with their purchase of an android phone. The plan is to give the customers SD cards with the app on.

My google-fu seemed to talk about Android requiring some DRM stuff on the SD card installed apps. Is this required or can i just toss the Android app on a FAT32 formatted SD card and it will work?

Answer (score 1):

You can stick the apk file on the sd card, but the customer will still need to allow installation from unknown sources, and will need a file browser to go open it and install it manually.

If all you want it to do is show a video, why not put it up on youtube or something and include a card with a QR code link to it or something?